# Updating with mongoose, not returning any errors but neither updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to learn CRUD with mongoose. I am only missing the update part. What am I doing wrong?

**MY MODEL**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    number: Number
});

mongoose.model('TestData', testSchema);
```

**MY ROUTES**

```
// get the models
var Test = mongoose.model('TestData');
```

*PARAM* 
 
If the link has the `'test'` as a url parameter, it will look if the object exist in the database, else return errors.

```
router.param('test', function(req, res, next, id){
    var query = Test.findById(id);

    query.exec(function(err, test){
        if(err){ return next(err); }
        if(!test){ return next(new Error('can\'t find test')); }
        req.test = test;
        return next();
    });
});
```

**GET BY ID**

```
    /* GET testdata/:id */
    router.get('/testingdata/:test', function(req, res, next){
        req.test.populate('test', function(err, test){
            res.json(test);
        });
    });
```

**DELETE**

```
/* DELETE testdata/:id */
router.delete('/testingdata/:test', function(req, res, next){
    req.test.remove('test', function(err, test){
        console.log('removed');
        res.json(test);
    });                         
});
```

**MY PROBLEM**
Now here comes my problem, if I try to update one, I am simply missing something.

```
/* PUT testdata/:id */
router.put('/testingdata/:test', function(req, res, next){
    req.test.update('test',{$set: {name: 'new data'}} , function(err, test){
        res.json(test);
    });                         
});
```

I am not getting any errors, but it is neither updating anything. It is even returning some data.

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try without unneeded first argument (`test`), because the `req.test` is an instance of the `Test` model.

```
req.test.update({name: 'new data'} , function(err, test){
  res.json(test); // test would be `1` if success
});
```

The `update` method will not return object, and if you want to return object then use `save`:

```
req.test.name = 'new data';
req.test.save(function(err, test){
  res.json(test);
});
```

Comment: Was exactly what I was looking for, it worked like a charm. Didn't knew the response data mattered with ok: 1 or ok: 0, glad you pointed that out. And thank for the save function, was indeed much better.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in that both the remove and the update methods, don't work on a model instance but require queries, like

```
{_id:id}
```

You update statement isn't matching anything, and I bet your remove endpoint won't work either.

If you want to operate on the live model instance on req.test then set the value on test directly and save the model:

```
req.test.name= 'new data';
req.test.save(...
```

Deleting a model is always going to require a new query as you can't delete an instance directly.

Comment: Hello Robert, thank you for your answer. But actually, after you said that that my remove endpoint wouldn't worked I freaked out and had to test it several times. And it seems that in fact it is working, but perhaps it is a bad habit deleting it like that? And you would recommend using the pure MongoDB syntax instead? {_id : test['_id'] }, {name : 'new data'}