# Using Put method with Express I get code 200 but nothing updated

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

Hello guys I just tried to create my update function and using Postman I want to update the `firstName` field. the result in console is HTTP/1.1" 200 but nothing updated.

This is the result in Postman body

```
{
    "user_id": "5adaa55c0364d01cd9478492",
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YWRhYTU1YzAzNjRkMDFjZDk0Nzg0OTIiLCJpYX4OTJ9.JpDShf4iBFBCQ5rGflKbsj3jisl-PS68UOTnVpxNyXs",
    "data": {
        "userData": [
            {
                "address": [
                    {}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is what I try to update

```
{
    "data": {
        "userData": [
            {
                "firstName": "George"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my update function from `authentication_controller.js`

```
exports.update = function (req, res, next) {
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var role = req.body.role;
  var firstName = req.body.firstName;
  var lastName = req.body.lastName;
  var phone = req.body.phone;
  var number = req.body.number;
  var street = req.body.street;
  var city = req.body.city;
  var postcode = req.body.postcode;
  var user = req.user;

  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    } else {
      res.json({
        user_id: user._id,
        token: tokenForUser(user),
        data: {
          email: email,
          password: password,
          userData: [{
            role: role,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            phone: phone,
            address: [{
              number: number,
              street: street,
              city: city,
              postcode: postcode
            }],
          }],
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

And here is the part from my `route.js`

```
router.route('/users/:user_id/data')
  .get(requireAuth, AuthenticationController.index)
  .put(requireAuth, AuthenticationController.update);
```

Comment: shouldnt you be using update and pass the updated object `user.update({data}, {options}, (err, raw) => { res.send(err ? err : raw)})`

Comment: @JoeWarner where is that `{options}` come from?

Comment: just a placeholder to say you can pass options in the second param just pass an empty object if you dont have any

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update

Comment: @JoeWarner and what is `raw` in this case because now the response is `{
    "ok": 0,
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031605/updating-with-mongoose-not-returning-any-errors-but-neither-updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling your mongoose model. You are calling the user object that is placed onto `req` by the `requireAuth` middleware from decoding the JWT.

You need to call/use your actual mongoose `User` model:

```
const User = require('./path/to/mongoose/model/User')

...

// assuming the decoded JWT user object has an `id` property
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, req.body)
    .exec()
    .then(doc => res.json(doc)
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: `const User = require('../models/user');` I am calling it I just didn't pasted this code in here

Comment: You are not. You are calling `user` from `req.user`. `user` is not the same as `User`.

Comment: That's not using it, that's *importing* it